# How would you give the user an option to open a URL from his native browser inside a WebView app?

Tags: android, webview

As I understand, I have to use `<intent-filter>` for users to get a prompt to open the file in your app. But I was wondering, how would you do that with URLs and WebView?

For example, let's say a user visits https://www.google.com/. Can visiting that URL somehow trigger a prompt that will let a user instead decide if he wants to open the URL inside the app, and view https://www.google.com/ though the WebView inside the app? If so, how would I go ahead and do that?

I will try to answer any questions. Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying the url is open in some browser like chrome and from there you want to know if some url is opened and show some dialog to user asking if he wants to open the same url in your application?

Comment: Yes. If some url is opened, give the user an option to open it in app.

Comment: You can get intent using <intent-filter> when user clicks on a url. An application chooser will be shown in which your application will be one. If user has opened url by typing in a browser like chrome, you can't know about it.

Comment: I see. So if they directly visit the website rather than through a link, it won't show the prompt. Thanks.